# AngularJS unknown provider: $routeProviderProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling with this unknown provider error and just wondering what I'm doing wrong. Have this structure:

in main.js

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['navService', function (navService) {
    this.awesomeThings = [
    'HTML5 Boilerplate',
    'AngularJS',
    'Karma'
];

  this.active = false;

  navService.getPosition();

}]);
```

In index html I have ng-controller="MainCtrl"
And finally in navService:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('navService', ['$routeProvider', '$location', function ($routeProvider, $location) {
    function getPosition() {
        /*code here */
    }

    return {
        getPosition: getPosition
    };
}]);
```

In main app.js

```
angular
  .module('cavyrApp', [
'ngAnimate',
'ngCookies',
'ngMessages',
'ngResource',
'ngRoute',
'ngSanitize',
'ngTouch'
  ]).config...........
```

Comment: did you include angular-route.js in your head section?

Comment: Also, did you inject `ngRoute` into your main app module declaration?

Comment: @SankarRaj - Yeah - both are there

Comment: There must be some other error in the console because if you have everything configured properly then you shouldn't be getting an unknown provider error. If you are using the minified version of Angular use the full version while developing and debugging so that you get more verbose error messages. With what you've given us to work with I don't think there's much we can do to help solve your issue.

Comment: The error in the console is only one: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProviderProvider <- $routeProvider <- navService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeProviderProvider%20%3C-%20%24routeProvider%20%3C-%20navService
minErr/<@http://localhost:9000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12

Comment: Are you using the same versions of `angular.js` and `angular-route.js`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$routeProvider` is a provider - you can not inject it into factory/service. You can inject it to the `config` method only - to configure the service it will provide:

```
module.config(function($routeProvider) {
    // configure the routes here
});
```

Comment: Yeah - that was it! Many Thanks - I was slipped by the error as it was saying that there is no navService, but apparently the real reason was wrong injection as you said.

Answer (score 0):

You should `inject` your `factroy` like this:

```
angular.module('myApp',['ngRoute']); //route inject
```

and the controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MainCtrl',  function(navService) {
});
```

Comment: Other than removing the injection annotation (which will cause the code to break if it's minified) this is **exactly** how the OP is using the factory.

Comment: This way doesn't work unfortunatelly. I removed the second argument array as you advised.